# Download the Complete Linux Kernel Collection

Tags: debian, kernel, linux-kernel, rpm

I am wanting to download EVERY version of the Linux kernel as source code, Debian files, and RPM files. Where can I find a single site where I can download them all at once? If that is not possible, I know I can get the source code for every kernel here (https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/), but I need the .deb and .rpm files as well.

Comment: Why do you want this?  What do you want to accomplish?  This sounds like a typical [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/169312).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd be surprised if you'd find every version as a .deb and .rpm on a single site. You'll be lucky if you find every version of the .rpms. I'd be very surprised.

You can reach back to Fedora Core 1 (FC1) through FC6 here on the [Fedora Project Archive](http://archive.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/core/). Fedora 7 through 18 (plus the latest) are available on the same site in a different directory [here](http://archive.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/).

The .deb files are available through the [Debian Distributions Archive](http://www.debian.org/distrib/archive) you can search through the archive [here](http://archive.debian.net/).

Comment: The Debian link works - it will take some time though to collect all of the kernel debs. However, the Fedora links do not have any rpm kernels. Instead, they are tarballs.

Comment: I will wait to see if anyone comes up with a better answer. If not, then I will mark yours as the answer (it does seem true that no site contains a complete collection).

Comment: @DevynCollierJohnson - Check again, they're hidden in directories like this: `/pub/archive/fedora/linux/core/1/i386/os/Fedora/RPMS/`.

Comment: @DevynCollierJohnson - The newer Fedora's are under a different structure: `/pub/fedora/linux/releases/17/Fedora/x86_64/os/Packages/`. It's a bit of a kludge.

Comment: @DevynCollierJohnson - you can use [httrack](http://httrack.kauler.com/help/Filters) to download files from a site. Use it's filtering feature to only download files that match the pattern `kernel.*.rpm`.

Answer (score 1):

RPM and deb archives are quite nice and handy, but chances are you won't get the official kernel that way but a patched version; most distributions ship modified kernels sources for many reasons (and may include bugfix backports, extra binary firmware blobs, code merged from third parties, and so on).

I strongly suggest you get the original kernel tarballs on [the official site](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/) and to save some bandwidth and time, you can get most of the minor releases via patches.